# Angular JS: ng-repeat not generating an expected outcome

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created an erray with name and extension property I want to traverse it using ng-repeat. 
May I know what am I doing wrong here?

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html lang="en" ng-app="">
    <head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Welcome to angular js</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div ng-init="myFavLanguage=[{name:'PHP', extension:'.php'},{name='JAVA', extnsion='.java'}]">

    <p ng-repeat="lang in myFavLanguage">
    Name: {{lang.name}}<br>
    Extension: {{lang.extension}}<br>
    </p>
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You forgot an `e` in extnsion. You used `=` instead of `:`. You used ng-init although it's clearly documented that you should avoid it. Putting this JS code in a js file is much easier for thre IDE to spot and signal the syntax errors. When asking a question like this, you must say what you expect to happen and what happens instead, including the error messages you get. Don't force us to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly assigning values in object  (in 'JAVA' part):

```
<div ng-init="myFavLanguage=[{name:'PHP', extension:'.php'},{name='JAVA', extnsion='.java'}]">
```

Change this to this:

```
<div ng-init="myFavLanguage=[{name: 'PHP', extension: '.php'}, {name: 'JAVA', extnsion: '.java'}]">
```